# How Do I Filter a Group of Rows based on one Column's Value in TSQL?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I am trying to make a SQL query in Server 2008 R2 that selects the rows only for employees who have over 40 hours in a pay week and a pay description that doesn't include "over time".  So far I have the following:

```
WITH RESULTS AS
(
SELECT 
      [FullName]
  ,[PayHours]
  ,[SSN]
  ,[EffectiveDate]
  ,[PayDescription]
  ,[OrderNumber]
  ,[WeekStart]
  ,[WeekEnd]
  ,SUM(PayHours)OVER(Partition BY FullName,WeekStart) AS TotalHours



  FROM [viewReportPotentialOverTime]

  WHERE EffectiveDate BETWEEN '01/01/2015 00:00:00' AND '10/23/2015 23:59:59' 
 Group By FullName,SSN,WeekStart, WeekEnd, EffectiveDate, OrderNumber, PayDescription, PayHours

  )
SELECT * FROM RESULTS
Having TotalHours > 40 --AND PayDescription !='Overtime Pay'
Order By FullName, WeekStart, EffectiveDate
```

This gets me close to what I need.  The problem I'm having is filtering out the rows for employees that do include a PayDesciption of 'Overtime Pay'.  When I uncomment the !='Overtime Pay' then it filters out just the one row for that pay week that was 'Overtime Pay' and leaves all of the Regular Pay rows. However, what I need is for it to filter out all rows for that pay week (which I used the WeekStart column to determine the pay weeks)for that employee. I'm using this as an audit to make sure whenever someone worked over 40 hours in a week that they were paid OT.

I've also tried a similar version using the HAVING clause, but the problem I run into there is that you can't have a windowed function in a HAVING clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need the `GROUP BY`, are those rows not distinct?

You can add a conditional `CASE` to find rows with *'Overtime Pay'*

```
WITH RESULTS AS
(
SELECT 
      [FullName]
  ,[PayHours]
  ,[SSN]
  ,[EffectiveDate]
  ,[PayDescription]
  ,[OrderNumber]
  ,[WeekStart]
  ,[WeekEnd]
  ,SUM(PayHours)
   OVER(Partition BY FullName,WeekStart) AS TotalHours
  ,MAX(CASE WHEN PayDescription ='Overtime Pay' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
   OVER(Partition BY FullName,WeekStart) AS OvertimePayFlag


  FROM [viewReportPotentialOverTime]

  WHERE EffectiveDate BETWEEN '01/01/2015 00:00:00' AND '10/23/2015 23:59:59' 

   -- really needed?
  Group By FullName,SSN,WeekStart, WeekEnd, EffectiveDate, OrderNumber, PayDescription, PayHours
  )
SELECT * FROM RESULTS
WHERE TotalHours > 40  -- no HAVING needed
  AND OvertimePayFlag = 1
Order By FullName, WeekStart, EffectiveDate
```

Comment: This worked like a charm!  Also, you're right... it turns out I didn't need the 'Group By' like you said.  Thanks.